# Does one need to flip the Torah exactly twice or more than this?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As a Torah reader, before starting to read the Torah, I flip it upside down about 50 times to obey Ben Bag Bag's adage,

Pirkei Avot 5:22:

> בֶּן בַּג בַּג אוֹמֵר, הֲפָךְ בָּהּ וַהֲפָךְ בָּהּ, דְּכֹלָּא בָה

"Turn it upside down and turn it upside down, because everything is in it."

Well, here's the problem. If I turn the Torah upside down twice (as seems to be implied by his saying this twice), I don't see the purpose because it's in the same position as when I began. So, what am I really accomplishing by doing it in the first place? Besides, he says that EVERYTHING is in it. I'm probably not going to find everything from just two flips.

SO, I think that Ben Bag Bag means, **continuously** flip it. But, truthfully, after a while, my head is spinning so much that my Torah reading is coming out upside down.

So, according to Ben Bag Bag, when should one stop?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You're supposed to shake it up to get the Cola to spray everywhere. Some are Machmir to put Mentos in too.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be assuming the "it" of Ben Bag Bag is the Torah. The subject which has everything in it is, in actuality, a person who has de'ah, as the Gemara in Nedarim 41a says

> אמר אביי, נקטינן: אין עני אלא בדעה.
>   במערבא אמרי:
>   דדא ביה – כולא ביה, דלא דא ביה – מה ביה?
>
> If de'ah is in him, everything is in him

So the Mishna refers to a Bar-Deah. Most probably Giora Bar Deah, CEO of Elite coffee manufacturer.

Now, it doesn't actually say הפך אותו, flip him, but rather הפך בה, flip *using* him.

If one wants to fulfill Ben Bag Bag's edict, he should drink Elite coffee until there is so much caffeine in his system that he begins uncontrollably twisting around and flipping.

If one wants to be really scrupulous, it is ideal to drink [קפה הפוך](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9A).

Answer (score 1):

Ben Bag Bag was such a good magician that he made his first name disappear!

If we remember this, it will be clear that this *mishna* is not about Torah reading, but in fact a magic trick, as we can see by looking at more of the *mishna*.  We have to look at the *girsa* of the *Gra* to get the full import:

> ‮בן בג בג אומר: [שויה בה ו]הפך בה והפך בה, והגי בה דכולא בה!
>
> Ben Bag Bag says: Put it in [the hat], turn [the hat] over, turn [the hat] over [again], and look into [the hat, and see] that everything is [still] in [the hat]!

We still don't know how Ben Bag Bag kept it from falling out of the hat.  Indeed, Ben Bag Bag was able to turn it into other objects (also in the *Gra*'s *girsa*):

> ‮וחזי בה: סי[ג] ובל[וט] בה!
>
> And look inside! Sproutings and acorns [are now] inside [the hat]!

The rest of that *mishna* is the beginning of another magic trick (ומינה לא תזוז: stand exactly in this spot...)